# Enlarging WebKit database size in Cocoa Application

Tags: cocoa, macos, webkit

I'm using WebKit.framework in my Cocoa application. However, [my application](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ogndknhgkahnialefpjkhmbekkobjfkh) *(I'm porting from Chrome webapp to native application to get it in the dock, a function that Chrome doesn't offer on the Mac)* seems to not loading and throwing DOM Exception 18.

Although I know that I requested too much size to `window.openDatabase`, but I'm sure that my application will need more than 5MB so I need to enlarge the database size somehow or disable the limit altogether (which I did in Chrome)